# how can i change NSToolbar (cocoa) background colour?

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar

I need to change toolbar colour of my mac application .While window in full screen mode if i set window background colour as red toolbar colour also changed to red.Normal case it shows default colour.Is it possible to change toolbar background to red?